Uable to Generate Output file using Make
I'm learning PWM on an STM32F446 nucleo board and following this tutorial series: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kHUGY05ImWU&t=854s. I'm using the Libopencm3 library and the ARM Cortex-M toolchain.  My project repository is as follows:
.
├── app/
│   ├── inc/
│   │   ├── common_defines.h
│   │   └── core/
│   │       ├── system.h
│   │       └── timer.h
│   └── src/
│       ├── firmware.c
│       └── core/
│           ├── system.c
│           └── timer.c
├── linkerscript.ld
├── makefile
└── libopencm3

I'm using make to build the project and the Makefile is as follows:


# Be silent per default, but 'make V=1' will show all compiler calls.
ifneq ($(V),1)
Q       := @
NULL        := 2>/dev/null
endif

SRC_DIR        = ./src
INC_DIR        = ./inc
OPENCM3_DIR    = ../libopencm3
VPATH += $(SRC_DIR)/core

BINARY = firmware

###############################################################################
# Basic Device Setup

LIBNAME         = opencm3_stm32f4
DEFS                += -DSTM32F4
FP_FLAGS        ?= -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16
ARCH_FLAGS  = -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m4 $(FP_FLAGS)

###############################################################################
# Linkerscript

LDSCRIPT = linkerscript.ld
LDLIBS      += -l$(LIBNAME)
LDFLAGS     += -L$(OPENCM3_DIR)/lib

###############################################################################
# Includes

DEFS        += -I$(OPENCM3_DIR)/include
DEFS        += -I$(INC_DIR)


###############################################################################
# Executables

PREFIX      ?= arm-none-eabi-

CC      := $(PREFIX)gcc
CXX     := $(PREFIX)g++
LD      := $(PREFIX)gcc
AR      := $(PREFIX)ar
AS      := $(PREFIX)as
OBJCOPY     := $(PREFIX)objcopy
OBJDUMP     := $(PREFIX)objdump
GDB     := $(PREFIX)gdb
STFLASH     = $(shell which st-flash)
OPT     := -Os
DEBUG       := -ggdb3
CSTD        ?= -std=c99


###############################################################################
# Source files

OBJS        += $(SRC_DIR)/$(BINARY).o
OBJS        += $(SRC_DIR)/core/system.o
OBJS        += $(SRC_DIR)/core/timer.o


###############################################################################
# C flags

TGT_CFLAGS  += $(OPT) $(CSTD) $(DEBUG)
TGT_CFLAGS  += $(ARCH_FLAGS)
TGT_CFLAGS  += -Wextra -Wshadow -Wimplicit-function-declaration
TGT_CFLAGS  += -Wredundant-decls -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes
TGT_CFLAGS  += -fno-common -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections

###############################################################################
# C++ flags

TGT_CXXFLAGS    += $(OPT) $(CXXSTD) $(DEBUG)
TGT_CXXFLAGS    += $(ARCH_FLAGS)
TGT_CXXFLAGS    += -Wextra -Wshadow -Wredundant-decls  -Weffc++
TGT_CXXFLAGS    += -fno-common -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections

###############################################################################
# C & C++ preprocessor common flags

TGT_CPPFLAGS    += -MD
TGT_CPPFLAGS    += -Wall -Wundef
TGT_CPPFLAGS    += $(DEFS)

###############################################################################
# Linker flags

TGT_LDFLAGS     += --static -nostartfiles
TGT_LDFLAGS     += -T$(LDSCRIPT)
TGT_LDFLAGS     += $(ARCH_FLAGS) $(DEBUG)
TGT_LDFLAGS     += -Wl,-Map=$(*).map -Wl,--cref
TGT_LDFLAGS     += -Wl,--gc-sections
ifeq ($(V),99)
TGT_LDFLAGS     += -Wl,--print-gc-sections
endif

###############################################################################
# Used libraries

LDLIBS      += -Wl,--start-group -lc -lgcc -lnosys -Wl,--end-group

###############################################################################
###############################################################################
###############################################################################

.SUFFIXES: .elf .bin .hex .srec .list .map .images
.SECONDEXPANSION:
.SECONDARY:

all: elf bin

elf: $(BINARY).elf
bin: $(BINARY).bin
hex: $(BINARY).hex
srec: $(BINARY).srec
list: $(BINARY).list
GENERATED_BINARIES=$(BINARY).elf $(BINARY).bin $(BINARY).hex $(BINARY).srec $(BINARY).list $(BINARY).map

images: $(BINARY).images
flash: $(BINARY).flash

$(OPENCM3_DIR)/lib/lib$(LIBNAME).a:
ifeq (,$(wildcard $@))
    $(warning $(LIBNAME).a not found, attempting to rebuild in $(OPENCM3_DIR))
    $(MAKE) -C $(OPENCM3_DIR)
endif

# Define a helper macro for debugging make errors online
# you can type "make print-OPENCM3_DIR" and it will show you
# how that ended up being resolved by all of the included
# makefiles.
print-%:
    @echo $*=$($*)

%.images: %.bin %.hex %.srec %.list %.map
    @#printf "*** $* images generated ***\n"

%.bin: %.elf
    @#printf "  OBJCOPY $(*).bin\n"
    $(Q)$(OBJCOPY) -Obinary $(*).elf $(*).bin

%.hex: %.elf
    @#printf "  OBJCOPY $(*).hex\n"
    $(Q)$(OBJCOPY) -Oihex $(*).elf $(*).hex

%.srec: %.elf
    @#printf "  OBJCOPY $(*).srec\n"
    $(Q)$(OBJCOPY) -Osrec $(*).elf $(*).srec

%.list: %.elf
    @#printf "  OBJDUMP $(*).list\n"
    $(Q)$(OBJDUMP) -S $(*).elf > $(*).list

%.elf %.map: $(OBJS) $(LDSCRIPT) $(OPENCM3_DIR)/lib/lib$(LIBNAME).a Makefile
    @#printf "  LD      $(*).elf\n"
    $(Q)$(LD) $(TGT_LDFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJS) $(LDLIBS) -o $(*).elf

%.o: %.c
    @#printf "  CC      $(*).c\n"
    $(Q)$(CC) $(TGT_CFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $(TGT_CPPFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -o $(*).o -c $(*).c

%.o: %.S
    @#printf "  CC      $(*).S\n"
    $(Q)$(CC) $(TGT_CFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -o $(*).o -c $(*).S

%.o: %.cxx
    @#printf "  CXX     $(*).cxx\n"
    $(Q)$(CXX) $(TGT_CXXFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) $(TGT_CPPFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -o $(*).o -c $(*).cxx

%.o: %.cpp
    @#printf "  CXX     $(*).cpp\n"
    $(Q)$(CXX) $(TGT_CXXFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) $(TGT_CPPFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -o $(*).o -c $(*).cpp

clean:
    @#printf "  CLEAN\n"
    $(Q)$(RM) $(GENERATED_BINARIES) generated.* $(OBJS) $(OBJS:%.o=%.d)


.PHONY: images clean elf bin hex srec list

-include $(OBJS:.o=.d)

When I try t build it, I get the following error:
$ make
In file included from ../libopencm3/include/libopencm3/stm32/common/timer_common_f24.h:31,
                 from ../libopencm3/include/libopencm3/stm32/f4/timer.h:35,
                 from src/timer.c:2:
../libopencm3/include/libopencm3/stm32/common/timer_common_all.h:1154:12: error: expected ';' before 'void'
 1154 | BEGIN_DECLS
      |            ^
      |            ;
 1155 |
 1156 | void timer_enable_irq(uint32_t timer_peripheral, uint32_t irq);
      | ~~~~
../libopencm3/include/libopencm3/stm32/common/timer_common_all.h:1245:10: error: expected ';' before 'enum'
 1245 | END_DECLS
      |          ^
      |          ;
../libopencm3/include/libopencm3/stm32/common/timer_common_f24.h:95:12: error: expected ';' before 'void'
   95 | BEGIN_DECLS
      |            ^
      |            ;
   96 |
   97 | void timer_set_option(uint32_t timer_peripheral, uint32_t option);
      | ~~~~
../libopencm3/include/libopencm3/stm32/common/timer_common_f24.h:101:10: error: expected ';' before 'void'
  101 | END_DECLS
      |          ^
      |          ;
make: *** [Makefile:163: src/timer.o] Error 1

The error points to the following lines in the Makefile:
%.o: %.c
    @#printf "  CC      $(*).c\n"
    $(Q)$(CC) $(TGT_CFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $(TGT_CPPFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -o $(*).o -c $(*).c

I am confused since the compiler was able to produce a system.o file, but not a timer.o file. I've tried using the Libopencm3 template github repo as a base for the project and modified the Makefile accordingly, but I end up with the same error message. I've also tried looking online, but couldn't find an appropriate solution.
Greatly appreciate the help!

There are compilation errors. You should look at the source code, not the Makefile.

The error message mentioning make is just a consequence of the actual errors. Make tells you why it stopped.

The errors are compiler errors, the make error is just showing you the rule that invoked the compiler.  Presumably an issue with whatever BEGIN_DECLS expands to after preprocessing.  Read error logs from the top, not from the bottom!
